# Couldn't rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

Tags: ros, coredump, abort

I am following the beginner rosnode tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes

The environment is Windows 10 / WSL. When I enter command "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node" after running "roscore", I get the following error:

`wn-003% rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
zsh: abort (core dumped)  rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node`

Are there any solutions to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WLS doesn't support graphical interfaces. You need to initialize some "x server for windows" application, like Xming and then type this line in WLS terminal:

`export DISPLAY=:0`

Answer (score 0):

ROS has a great open source ecosystem and support for Linux Operating system. For a beginner, it is better to get hands-on experience directly on a Linux machine as it is easier and you'll get good support for errors you encounter.

ROS does work on windows but it requires Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), which is a compatibility layer which allows running a whole bunch of Linux binaries natively on Windows 10. With the advent of the Windows 10 Creators Update, the WSL was heavily updated and now is able to run ROS lunar and melodic.

You will also need to install BASH shell on your windows 10 machine.

Follow this article by Microsoft for installing WSL and BASH : [install WSL on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10?ranMID=43674&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-xbKKNQFZ2pEBvpXLzMWX8Q&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-xbKKNQFZ2pEBvpXLzMWX8Q&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir__nz2jm6uurlai1ss1pfq6a3xw9v2xhe6zr6rrpjkx00)(7795)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-xbKKNQFZ2pEBvpXLzMWX8Q)()&irclickid=_nz2jm6uurlai1ss1pfq6a3xw9v2xhe6zr6rrpjkx00)

Then follow this great article by janbernloehr : https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows